# В чем может быть проблема? Пытался переустановить aiogram, установить более позднюю версию и самую последнюю, но ничего не помогает

Tags: python, aiogram

```
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def StartMessage(message: types.Message):
  await message.answer("HI")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  dp.start_polling(bot)
```

**Ошибка:**

```
TypeError: Dispatcher.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос на enSO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77278547/dispatcher-init-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given